# Checking if date if formatted properly and ignoring if there are spaces before or after date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to identify whether a date is formatted incorrectly in SQL.

I want it to be `DD/MM/YYYY`, and I do not want the date to be considered improperly formatted if there are leading spaces or a space after the date.

Currently, my code is considering a date with a space after the date an improperly formatted date.

My code is the following:

```
\\other stuff here 

when REGEXP_LIKE(replace(column_name, ' '), '^[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]')

    then 1

\\other stuff here
```

Comment: i see no point in doing this. you are using `replace` incorrectly as you are missing a third argument. Use `TRIM` instead to remove all leading and trailing spaces

Comment: You don't need to handle spaces at all when using TO_DATE function, just secure the numbers and separators are correct. For instance this is very much correct input: `TO_DATE('   1234   -   05   -   12   12       :   34   : 56  ', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression does not work. For example `19/39/2015` would be considered as valid.

I recommend to use a function:

```
create or replace function String2Date(str in vahrchar2) as integer is
   d DATE;
begin
   if REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(str), '^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$') then
      d := TO_DATE(str, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
   end if;
exception
   when others then
       return 0;
end;
```